# Как лучше всего реализовывать такие окна?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такие товары

При клике должно такое окно выскакивать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у разного товара выходит разные фотографии должны быть. И разное описание. Как лучше всего реализовывать? Если есть хорошие знания HTML, CSS, чуть меньше базы JS,

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема?То что на картинке,можно и на чистом css сделать,можно на js и тп... Как лучше реализовывать для чего?

Comment: По клику делаете запрос в бд, получаете результат, формируете блок, выводите popup.

Comment: @E_K нет знаний PHP, MySQL

Comment: @E_K это же на jquery можно сделать ... только получится статически

Comment: лучше на дивах )

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, если вы хотите сделать просто HTML шаблон вам PHP и MySQL не нужен. По клику открывайте popup с информацией о товаре. Если вы хотите в простом шаблоне сделать это для каждого товара, то прийдется сделать popup для каждого товара и открывать в зависимости от того на какой товар нажали.